# Combination of Token pasting and stringizing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Following is the code including Combination of Token pasting and Stringizing as follows:

```
#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a) #a
#define h(a) g(a)

printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2))); 
printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
```

The output is:

```
12

f(1,2)
```

I do not uderstand the difference in ordering in the two expressions.

Comment: @user93353 "possible duplicate"? It's a clone.

Comment: @SuvP - the comment "possible duplicate" is automatically inserted when you vote to close a Question as a duplicate.

Comment: @user93353 oh! I didnt notice that when i flag questions. Good to know.

Comment: @SuvP - doesn't happen when you flag questions. It happens only when you vote to close.

Comment: @user93353 Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `#` expression in the preprocessor, it takes the incoming argument and makes a string of it.

In your code:

```
#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a) #a
#define h(a) g(a)

printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2))); 
printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
```

when you call `h(f(1,2))`, it translates to `g(f(1,2))`, which in turn is a macro, so the macro expander parses that, *starting from the inside* with `f(1,2)`, which is `12`, then passes that as `g(12)`, which results in `"12"`.

With `g(f(1,2))`, `f(1,2)` is used directly, because there is no expansion of with `#a`, it just uses whatever is passed in as `a`.

Comment: this explanation is better then linked answer, but I have confusion why `g(f(1,2))` starts from inside for `h(f(1,2))`

Comment: It's not so much that it starts from the inside, but rather that the C preprocessor expands the macro `f(1,2) before passing it to `g` when calling `h`. When calling `g` directly, it just passes `f(1,2)` to the `g` macro. It's the way it works - I can't really explain it better.